# anova function with only 1 model

Tags: r

I am  not very clear what anova {stats} with only 1 object does, and how to interpret the result. I know with multiple models, anova compares the models and assess whether or not the new model is different from the previous.

According to R's help page, "When given a single argument it produces a table which tests whether the model terms are significant". What does it mean by the significance of model terms?

I also need to interpret the following:

Given x1 and x2 are both continuous predictors, construct model

lm1 <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2)

then,

anova(lm1) gives:

> ```
> Analysis of Variance Table
>
> Response: y
>
>     Df    Sum Sq    Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)  
>
> x1   1 0.0007706 0.00077060  5.8930 0.02243 *
>
> x2   1 0.0008881 0.00088807  6.7913 0.01496 *
>
> Residuals     26 0.0033999 0.00013077
> ```

How can I interpret the p value here? What should I do to describe whether or not x1 or x2 significantly contribute to the model?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It simply carries out the analysis of (co)variance, I imagine. Try this:

```
aov.model <- aov(y ~ x1 + x2)
summary(aov.model)
```

You will get the same results as with

```
anova(lm1)
```

See the discussion [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/lm-ANOVA-vs-AOV-td819452.html).

Comment: Thanks for the response. They are the same. However, I noticed that the p-values for summary(lm1) is different from summary(aov.model) or anova(lm1). Which one should I use? How can I interpret each p-value?

Comment: I believe the answer to that is here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28938/why-do-linear-regression-and-anova-give-different-p-value-in-case-of-consideri

Comment: Thanks. That answered all the questions I have.